# Trying to OrderBy Date on list returned in C# (Umbraco 4.8.1)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, api, umbraco

I'm trying to pull the latest 5 articles from the news section and then sort them by the article date.

I've managed to get the 5 articles and display them ok, but the OrderBy is not working as expected. I need to sort them by a property on the node called "NewsDate" which is a date picker.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentNode = Node.GetCurrent();
        var nodeTypeAlias = currentNode.NodeTypeAlias;

        if (nodeTypeAlias == "NewsMasterPage")
        {
            var nodes = FindChildren(currentNode, t => t.NodeTypeAlias.Equals("NewsArticle"));
            var nodesOutput = nodes.OrderBy(n => n.GetProperty("NewsDate"));

            newsRepeater.DataSource = nodesOutput;
            newsRepeater.DataBind();
        }

    }

    private static List<Node> FindChildren(Node currentNode, Func<Node, bool> predicate)
    {
        List<Node> result = new List<Node>();

        var nodes = currentNode
            .Children
            .OfType<Node>()
            .Where(predicate).Take(4);
        if (nodes.Count() != 0)
            result.AddRange(nodes);

        foreach (var child in currentNode.Children.OfType<Node>())
        {
            nodes = FindChildren(child, predicate);
            if (nodes.Count() != 0)
                result.AddRange(nodes);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is because `GetProperty(string)` returns an object, not an actual `DateTime` instance. I believe you should be able to sort, if you create a transitional projection and then select the element later like so:

```
nodes.Select(x => new { Node = x, NewsDate = /* Convert x.GetProperty("NewsDate") to DateTime */ })
     .OrderBy(x => x.NewsDate)
     .Select(x => x.Node)
```